# Angular compile HTML and prevent changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some templates that i'm populating with some data from my DB using angular $compile. I have then to insert that inside an iframe to display it to the user and later save it on the database.

My problem is that when i get the template out of the scope the data that was placed inside it by binding the content disappears. What do i have to do to keep the binded data ?

I have tried to create a new scope and use the existing one, in both cases it fails.

This is where i compile the content:

```
//Method is called by the user
$scope.mountTemplate = function() {

    //Load the template the user chose before
    TemplateLoader.getTemplate($scope.modelTemplate.template + '.html').then(function(responseTemplate) {

        //Load the template the user chose before, here i just read the html from a file
        loadRegisters(url, $scope.formContentData.selected, append)
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.itensTemplate = response.map(function(elem) { return configRegisters(elem); });

                var compiledHTML = $compile(responseTemplate)($scope);

                //Here the data appears
                $('#divVisualizer').append(compiledHTML);

                $timeout(function() {
                    //At this point, when i log it the ng-repeat and other binded data disappears
                    console.log('compiledHTML', compiledHTML);
                }, 1000);

                //At this point, when i place it inside the iframe the ng-repeat and other binded data disappears
                $scope.trustedHTML = compiledHTML;
            }, function(response) {
                console.log('response', response);
            });
    }, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

What should i do to keep the binded data ? Also i need the response of the compile to be an string, it comes back as an object. How can i convert it ?

**EDIT**

To clarify what my app does: I'm build a newsletter builder where the user chooses some registers from the database and a template to be filled with those registers and after that it is saved on the DB to be sent via email later.

Comment: what does call this loadRegisters?

Comment: You should use the concept of directives that is used in angular when we want to play with DOM.

Comment: The loadRegisters is inside another scope method that is called when the user chooses to generate the template. I can't use a directive with this because i don't really want the template placed on the page, i need it to be saved on the database.

Comment: You shouldn't mix jQuery and AngularJS. If you want to inject data and markup inside a div, use directives(either directly or with transclusion).

Comment: @cst1992 i'm quite new to angular, could you please provide an example of how i could achieve what i want using those methods ? I played with directives already but i can't imagine how i'm going to populate the template with the directive and later retrieve that html to save it on the DB.

Comment: Angular directives is a vast topic. But if you're generating templates then I can guess that they are somewhat similar, just that the data changes. In AngularJS the way you work is that you keep your templates in files, and exchange data across with services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem working with a service and a directive and also using defer to help load and populating the data